# getBodyDocument returns null

Tags: apex, httprequest, dom

I'm trying to write tests using httpCalloutMock in a fashion similar to

```
global class MyHttpMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest httpRequest){
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();


        DOM.Document domDoc = httpRequest.getBodyDocument();

        // insert logic here...

        return res;
    }
}
```

However the getBodyDocument call is returning null. According to the documentation at 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm

the getBodyDocument call is equivalent to

```
String xml = httpRequest.getBody();
Dom.Document domDoc = new Dom.Document(xml);
```

but Dom.Document doesn't have a string constructor. So instead i tried

```
DOM.Document domDoc = new DOM.Document();
domDoc.load(httpRequest.getBody());
```

which seems to work fine. Is there a reason why getBodyDocument is returning null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the document yourself in order to use it in a mock callout:

```
HttpRequest r = new HttpRequest();
Dom.Document body = new Dom.Document();
body.load('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><child /></root>');
r.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
r.setBodyDocument(body);
```

[HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) does mention the Dom.Document version of this method in its list of methods.

Interestingly, there's a string-based version that fails with an interesting compilation error (v37.0):

```
HttpRequest r = new HttpRequest();
r.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
r.setBodyDocument('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><child /></root>');
```

This fails with the compilation error: "Method not yet implemented"

This suggests that the developers have a stub for it, but it doesn't work yet.

I find both methods rather annoying, as you'd not normally use setBodyDocument in a "real" HttpRequest, and yet they force you to do so if you want to be able to use it in a unit test.

Comment: Just tried this, and interestingly the opposite is also true. If you use setBodyDocument, getBody no longer works